# Sending a warning message to certain users open terminals in tcl script

Tags: linux, terminal, tcl

When running a section of my tcl script I would like to warn certain users with open terminals of what is happening. At the same time letting them know which terminal the message is being sent from. So far I have:

```
set who [exec who]
set user [lindex $who 0]
set who [split $who "\n"]

for { set i 0 } { $i < [llength $who] } { incr i } {
    set current [lindex $who $i]
    exec write $user [lindex $current 1]
    # I would now like to send a message to this user
}
```

Except when I hit the "write" section the code gets stuck. As it can't exit. How do I pass tcl for shell variables to be written to desired user's terminal? Then exit the write section?

It does not look like i can use the "wall" command in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to supply an actual message to send. Assuming you are sending the same message to each, just put the message in a variable at the top of your script and use a heredoc with `exec` to supply it as `write`'s standard input.

```
set who [exec who]
set user [lindex $who 0]
set who [split $who "\n"]
set message "The quick brown fox is jumping over the lazy dog.\n"

for { set i 0 } { $i < [llength $who] } { incr i } {
    set current [lindex $who $i]
    exec write $user [lindex $current 1] << $message
}
```

Comment: This appears to work when I try it, but I'm on OSX so you might have some differences.